# What is the minimum code required to produce random numbers in Elm?

Tags: random, elm

I just want to see a random number. So here's [an example straight out of the docs](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.0.0/Random#generate) for the Random library. I expect `Random.generate` to accept a generator and a seed and return a tuple containing a random value and a new seed, as in:

`generate : Generator a -> Seed -> (a, Seed)`

```
-- Main.elm

import Random

seed0 = Random.initialSeed 31415
randomNumber = Random.generate (Random.int 0 10) seed0
main = 
  -- print result of randomNumber here
```

The compiler errors show two type mismatches:

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------------- -----------

The 2nd argument to function `generate` is causing a mismatch.

5|        Random.generate (Random.int 0 10) seed0
                                        ^^^^^
Function `generate` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    Random.Generator a

But it is:

    Random.Seed


The 1st argument to function `generate` is causing a mismatch.

5|        Random.generate (Random.int 0 10) seed0
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `generate` is expecting the 1st argument to be:

    a -> b

But it is:

    Random.Generator Int
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: http://elm-lang.org/examples/random

Comment: Do I really need an entire elm app to see one instance of a random number? Another way of framing my question is "How much can I delete from the example you just posted and not get a type error?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of the docs you refer to is Core 1.0.0, which is old. Current version of Core is 4.0.5. ([docs for Random here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/Random))

The function with the signature you are looking for is now named `step`:

```
step : Generator a -> Seed -> (a, Seed)
```

So your refactored code would look something like this:

```
import Html exposing (text)
import Random

seed0 = Random.initialSeed 31415
(randomNumber, nextSeed) = Random.step (Random.int 0 10) seed0

main =
  text <| toString randomNumber
```

Comment: That is exactly the problem. I should PR the Gitbook to update their docs link. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the shortest example I can think of.
Because it is giving a constant seed, it will return same boolean.

If you need random number get produced at runtime, then you
 have to use `Random.generate` which produces `Cmd`
 so that elm runtime can get the randomness.
In this case, some form of `Platform.Program`
is needed because it is the only way to run `Cmd`.

```
import Html exposing (text)
import Random exposing (..)

main =
  text <| toString <| Tuple.first <| step bool (initialSeed 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

##### Elm 2022 (v0.19) answer:

Here's an absolute minimal example for generating a number between 0 and 1000 in Elm 0.19.1, and [a runnable Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/hqsvxX694JMa1), which depends on [elm/random](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/1.0.2/). You wouldn't usually have all the `()` littered throughout, and instead you'd have `Msg` and `Model`, but in the interest of minimizing code:

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html
import Random


view : () -> Html.Html ()
view model =
    let
        -- this generates the rng number
        generator =
            Random.int 0 1000

        -- used to seed the generator
        seed =
            Random.initialSeed 12345

        -- Random.step returns the generated value, and a new seed.
        -- Usually you store the newSeed on your model so you don't always generate the same value
        ( value, newSeed ) =
            Random.step
                generator
                seed
    in
    Html.text <| String.fromInt value


main : Program () () ()
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = ()
        , view = view
        , update = \msg model -> model
        }
```

Other best practices include storing some global seed on the model:

```
type alias Model = { globalSeed : Random.Seed }
```

and then using it and updating the one on the model after:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd.none)
update msg model =
    case msg of
       GenerateValue ->
          let
             (newValue, newSeed) =
               Random.step (Random.int 0 1000) model.globalSeed

             _ =
               Debug.log "generated a new value" newValue

          in
          ( {model | globalSeed = newSeed}, Cmd.none)
```